# JNA Link failure and JMX unable to receive remote Connections and Out of memory error after running cassandra command on Windows

Tags: cassandra

```
WARNING! Powershell script execution unavailable.
   Please use 'powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted'
   on this user-account to run cassandra with fully featured
   functionality on this platform.
Starting with legacy startup options
Starting Cassandra Server
INFO  06:39:05 Node configuration:[authenticator=AllowAllAuthenticator; authorizer=AllowAllAuthorizer; auto_bootstrap=true; auto_snapshot=true; batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb=50; batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb=5; batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb=1024; broadcast_address=null; broadcast_rpc_address=null; cas_contention_timeout_in_ms=1000; client_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; cluster_name=Test Cluster; column_index_size_in_kb=64; commit_failure_policy=stop; commitlog_compression=null; commitlog_directory=null; commitlog_max_compression_buffers_in_pool=3; commitlog_periodic_queue_size=-1; commitlog_segment_size_in_mb=32; commitlog_sync=periodic; commitlog_sync_batch_window_in_ms=null; commitlog_sync_period_in_ms=10000; commitlog_total_space_in_mb=null; compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb=100; compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec=16; concurrent_compactors=null; concurrent_counter_writes=32; concurrent_reads=32; concurrent_replicates=null; concurrent_writes=32; counter_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; counter_cache_save_period=7200; counter_cache_size_in_mb=null; counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; cross_node_timeout=false; data_file_directories=[Ljava.lang.String;@2d127a61; disk_access_mode=auto; disk_failure_policy=stop; dynamic_snitch=true; dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold=0.1; dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms=600000; dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms=100; enable_user_defined_functions=false; encryption_options=null; endpoint_snitch=SimpleSnitch; file_cache_size_in_mb=null; gc_log_threshold_in_ms=200; gc_warn_threshold_in_ms=0; hinted_handoff_enabled=true; hinted_handoff_enabled_by_dc=[]; hinted_handoff_enabled_global=true; hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb=1024; incremental_backups=false; index_interval=null; index_summary_capacity_in_mb=null; index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes=60; initial_token=null; inter_dc_stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec=200; inter_dc_tcp_nodelay=false; internode_authenticator=null; internode_compression=all; internode_recv_buff_size_in_bytes=null; internode_send_buff_size_in_bytes=null; key_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; key_cache_save_period=14400; key_cache_size_in_mb=null; listen_address=localhost; listen_interface=null; listen_interface_prefer_ipv6=false; listen_on_broadcast_address=false; max_hint_window_in_ms=10800000; max_hints_delivery_threads=2; max_streaming_retries=3; memory_allocator=null; memtable_allocation_type=heap_buffers; memtable_cleanup_threshold=null; memtable_flush_writers=null; memtable_heap_space_in_mb=null; memtable_offheap_space_in_mb=null; native_transport_max_concurrent_connections=-1; native_transport_max_concurrent_connections_per_ip=-1; native_transport_max_frame_size_in_mb=256; native_transport_max_threads=128; native_transport_port=9042; num_tokens=256; otc_coalescing_enough_coalesced_messages=8; otc_coalescing_strategy=TIMEHORIZON; otc_coalescing_window_us=200; partitioner=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner; permissions_cache_max_entries=1000; permissions_update_interval_in_ms=-1; permissions_validity_in_ms=2000; phi_convict_threshold=8.0; range_request_timeout_in_ms=10000; read_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; request_scheduler=org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler; request_scheduler_id=null; request_scheduler_options=null; request_timeout_in_ms=10000; role_manager=CassandraRoleManager; roles_cache_max_entries=1000; roles_update_interval_in_ms=-1; roles_validity_in_ms=2000; row_cache_class_name=org.apache.cassandra.cache.OHCProvider; row_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; row_cache_save_period=0; row_cache_size_in_mb=0; rpc_address=localhost; rpc_interface=null; rpc_interface_prefer_ipv6=false; rpc_keepalive=true; rpc_listen_backlog=50; rpc_max_threads=2147483647; rpc_min_threads=16; rpc_port=9160; rpc_recv_buff_size_in_bytes=null; rpc_send_buff_size_in_bytes=null; rpc_server_type=sync; saved_caches_directory=null; seed_provider=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider{seeds=127.0.0.1}; server_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; snapshot_before_compaction=false; ssl_storage_port=7001; sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb=50; start_native_transport=true; start_rpc=false; storage_port=7000; stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec=200; streaming_socket_timeout_in_ms=86400000; thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb=15; thrift_max_message_length_in_mb=16; tombstone_failure_threshold=100000; tombstone_warn_threshold=1000; tracetype_query_ttl=86400; tracetype_repair_ttl=604800; trickle_fsync=false; trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb=10240; truncate_request_timeout_in_ms=60000; unlogged_batch_across_partitions_warn_threshold=10; windows_timer_interval=1; write_request_timeout_in_ms=2000]
INFO  06:39:05 DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
INFO  06:39:05 Global memtable on-heap threshold is enabled at 494MB
INFO  06:39:05 Global memtable off-heap threshold is enabled at 494MB
WARN  06:39:05 Only 0 MB free across all data volumes. Consider adding more capacity to your cluster or removing obsolete snapshots
INFO  06:39:06 Hostname: DESKTOP-ENNEVON
INFO  06:39:06 JVM vendor/version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_202
INFO  06:39:06 Heap size: 2075918336/2075918336
INFO  06:39:06 Code Cache Non-heap memory: init = 2555904(2496K) used = 3434432(3353K) committed = 3473408(3392K) max = 251658240(245760K)
INFO  06:39:06 Metaspace Non-heap memory: init = 0(0K) used = 14913296(14563K) committed = 15073280(14720K) max = -1(-1K)
INFO  06:39:06 Compressed Class Space Non-heap memory: init = 0(0K) used = 1890904(1846K) committed = 1966080(1920K) max = 1073741824(1048576K)
INFO  06:39:06 Par Eden Space Heap memory: init = 572653568(559232K) used = 103078120(100662K) committed = 572653568(559232K) max = 572653568(559232K)
INFO  06:39:06 Par Survivor Space Heap memory: init = 71565312(69888K) used = 0(0K) committed = 71565312(69888K) max = 71565312(69888K)
INFO  06:39:06 CMS Old Gen Heap memory: init = 1431699456(1398144K) used = 0(0K) committed = 1431699456(1398144K) max = 1431699456(1398144K)
INFO  06:39:06 Classpath: C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\conf;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\airline-0.6.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\apache-cassandra-2.2.17.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\apache-cassandra-clientutil-2.2.17.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\apache-cassandra-thrift-2.2.17.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\cassandra-driver-core-2.2.0-rc2-SNAPSHOT-20150617-shaded.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\commons-cli-1.1.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\commons-codec-1.2.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\commons-lang3-3.1.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\commons-math3-3.2.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\crc32ex-0.1.1.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\disruptor-3.0.1.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\ecj-4.4.2.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\guava-16.0.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\high-scale-lib-1.0.6.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\jamm-0.3.0.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\javax.inject.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\jbcrypt-0.3m.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\jna-4.0.0.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\joda-time-2.4.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\json-simple-1.1.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\libthrift-0.9.2.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\logback-classic-1.1.3.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\logback-core-1.1.3.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\lz4-1.3.0.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\metrics-core-3.1.0.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\metrics-jvm-3.1.0.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\metrics-logback-3.1.0.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\netty-all-4.0.44.Final.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\ohc-core-0.3.4.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\ohc-core-j8-0.3.4.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\reporter-config-base-3.0.0.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\reporter-config3-3.0.0.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\sigar-1.6.4.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\snakeyaml-1.11.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\snappy-java-1.1.1.7.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\ST4-4.0.8.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\stream-2.5.2.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\super-csv-2.1.0.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\thrift-server-0.3.7.jar;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\build\classes\main;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\build\classes\thrift;C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\jamm-0.3.0.jar
INFO  06:39:06 JVM Arguments: [-ea, -javaagent:C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\jamm-0.3.0.jar, -Xms2G, -Xmx2G, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:+UseParNewGC, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled, -XX:SurvivorRatio=8, -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml, -Djava.library.path=C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\lib\sigar-bin, -Dcassandra.jmx.local.port=7199, -Dcassandra, -Dcassandra-foreground=yes, -Dcassandra.logdir=C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\logs, -Dcassandra.storagedir=C:\apache-cassandra-2.2.17\data]
WARN  06:39:06 JNA link failure, one or more native method will be unavailable.
WARN  06:39:06 JMX is not enabled to receive remote connections. Please see cassandra-env.sh for more info.
WARN  06:39:06 The JVM is not configured to stop on OutOfMemoryError which can cause data corruption. Use one of the following JVM options to configure the behavior on OutOfMemoryError:  -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError, or -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="<cmd args>;<cmd args>"
INFO  06:39:06 Initializing SIGAR library
WARN  06:39:06 Cassandra server running in degraded mode. Is swap disabled? : false,  Address space adequate? : true,  nofile limit adequate? : true, nproc limit adequate? : true
Exception (java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError) encountered during startup: null
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.checkHealth(SystemKeyspace.java:709)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StartupChecks$9.execute(StartupChecks.java:351)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StartupChecks.verify(StartupChecks.java:109)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:188)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:607)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:717)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad configuration; unable to start server: At least one DataFileDirectory must be specified
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.createAllDirectories(DatabaseDescriptor.java:846)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.<clinit>(Keyspace.java:66)
        ... 6 more
ERROR 06:39:06 Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.checkHealth(SystemKeyspace.java:709) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.17.jar:2.2.17]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StartupChecks$9.execute(StartupChecks.java:351) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.17.jar:2.2.17]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StartupChecks.verify(StartupChecks.java:109) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.17.jar:2.2.17]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:188) [apache-cassandra-2.2.17.jar:2.2.17]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:607) [apache-cassandra-2.2.17.jar:2.2.17]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:717) [apache-cassandra-2.2.17.jar:2.2.17]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad configuration; unable to start server: At least one DataFileDirectory must be specified
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.createAllDirectories(DatabaseDescriptor.java:846) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.17.jar:2.2.17]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.<clinit>(Keyspace.java:66) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.17.jar:2.2.17]
        ... 6 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2):

On first glance it appears that Cassandra is failing to start because the data file directories are not configured:

```
unable to start server: At least one DataFileDirectory must be specified at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.createAllDirectories(DatabaseDescriptor.java:846) at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.(Keyspace.java:66)
```

In the configuration stack I can also see this, confirming the cause:

```
 data_file_directories=[Ljava.lang.String;@2d127a61
```

If that's the issue, you need to specify at least one path in cassandra.yaml under the parameter `data_file_directories:`

I don't see any sign of OutOfMemory(OOM) errors in your log. However, as specified in the respective WARN entry, it's recommended to auto-stop Cassandra on a JVM OOM by adding one of the following options to `cassandra-env.sh` (Linux) or `cassandra-env.ps1`(Windows):

- `-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError`
- `-XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError`
- `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=";"`

Answer (score 2):

This log message indicates that the Java Native Access (JNA) library could not locate some Windows libraries (DLLs):

```
WARN  06:39:06 JNA link failure, one or more native method will be unavailable.
```

This is almost always an environmental issue specific to your laptop/desktop/machine where some Windows dependency is not installed/configured correctly. In any case, Cassandra uses JNA mostly for accessing the disk to create hardlinks for snapshots (backups). This functionality is not required for Cassandra to operate which is why the message is logged at `WARN` level (instead of `ERROR`).

---

This log message simply warns you that JMX is not accessible remotely:

```
WARN  06:39:06 JMX is not enabled to receive remote connections. \
  Please see cassandra-env.sh for more info.
```

Java Management Extensions (JMX) exposes Java MBeans through management APIs so you can perform admin operations on components of Cassandra. You have [to explicitly configure JMX to accept connections remotely in `conf/cassandra-env.sh`](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.2.17/conf/cassandra-env.sh#L275-L317) otherwise you can only connect to it locally via `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`).

Again, remote JMX access is not necessary to operate Cassandra so the message is logged at `WARN` level instead of `ERROR`.

---

As this log states, you have not configured the Cassandra JVM to stop on `OutOfMemoryError`:

```
WARN  06:39:06 The JVM is not configured to stop on OutOfMemoryError which can cause \
  data corruption. Use one of the following JVM options to configure the behavior \
  on OutOfMemoryError:  -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError, \
  or -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="<cmd args>;<cmd args>"
```

You have [to configure the JVM with how to behave on an `OutOfMemoryError` in `conf/cassandra-env.sh`](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.2.17/conf/cassandra-env.sh#L207-L214).

---

As this error message states, a data directory was not configured (Cassandra got `null` from the configuration file):

```
ERROR 06:39:06 Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad configuration; unable to start server: \
  At least one DataFileDirectory must be specified
        ...
```

You need [to configure at least one data directory in `conf/cassandra.yaml`](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.2.17/conf/cassandra.yaml#L130-L135). For example:

```
data_file_directories:
    - /var/lib/cassandra/data
```

---

I should mention that running Cassandra on Windows has always been problematic for many years now and in fact, we stopped testing due to known issues with Java file I/O particularly with NTFS. It is a constant source of problems for users so as a project, we decided to officially drop support in 2020 -- see [the discussion on the project's `dev` thread](https://lists.apache.org/thread/cpbpx74ysrs7xwgklpx2wh6003jms260) and [CASSANDRA-16171](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16171).

The suggested alternatives for Windows users are:

- Deploy [Cassandra in Docker](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/quickstart.html)
- Deploy Cassandra in a VM using software like VirtualBox
- Deploy Cassandra in a Kubernetes cluster with open-source [K8ssandra.io](https://k8ssandra.io/get-started/)

Otherwise if you just want to learn how to build apps on Cassandra, [Astra DB](https://dtsx.io/2XM1INf) has a free tier where you can launch a Cassandra cluster in just 5 clicks with no credit card required. Cheers!